dbms_sql cursor_name as a parameter error
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fpp2(cur IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
IS 
rows_processed INTEGER;
BEGIN 
      dbms_output.PUT_LINE('cursor_fp2:' || cur);
      rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
     RETURN rows_processed;
END;
 

DECLARE 
    cur INTEGER;
    rows_processed INTEGER;
BEGIN
    cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, 'select * from t1',
                   DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
   -- rows_processed:=  DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
     dbms_output.PUT_LINE('cursor_nam:' || cur);
     rows_processed := fpp2(cur);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE('1234');
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE('123'|| sqlerrm);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
END;



result is ORA-29470 effective user or roles are not the same when the cursor was parsed
how  to fix fpp2 function ?
oracle dbms_sql not support cursor as parameter ?

Your code works fiddle and the issue cannot be reproduced. Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] including details of: which user owns the fpp2 function; which user is running the PL/SQL block; the CREATE TABLE statement for table t1 (including details of the owner); details of grants/synonyms on the function to the calling user; the full error message; and the expected output.

Does your user own fpp2, or is it in some other schema with default definer rights?

Change the definition of  fpp2 to  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fpp2(cur IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER AUTHID CURRENT_USER and see where that gets you.

thanks , function  fpp2 need AUTHID CURRENT_USER

Feel free to post the solution as an answer.  (You can answer your own question. )
